# Highway battle background score

Tags: soundtrack, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

What is the background score played in [*Captain America: The Winter Soldier*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843866/) when Captain America attacks the Winter Soldier right after Black Widow was shot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after  Natasha Romanoff / Black Widow was shot by Winter soldier, this is the soundtrack gets played

> 13.The Causeway

It starts with kind of a shrieking sound. Here's the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OV_IuELIiYE)